# how to retrieve jive hierarchy using REST API v3.14?

Tags: hierarchy, jive

No link was found to get jive hierarchy using REST API v3.14, i have to finish this task as early as possible.

Please help me out of this.
Thank You.

Comment: You would need to script this, starting with the result from calling /places/root, then following the resource link for "places".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Space hierarchy can be obtained by calling the places endpoint on the space itself.

For example lets say for spaces A,B,D in your diagram:

A.id = 1

B.id = 2

D.id = 4

if we call /api/core/v3/places/1/places, we should get back a list of spaces, projects and blogs whose parent is A which includes space B.

if we call /api/core/v3/places/2/places we should get a list with space D.

If you know your starting place, you can retrieve the full hierarchy by recursing down the tree like that.

Social Groups are different. Groups themselves have no hierarchy, its a flat structure. They do, however, still have a /places endpoint. This endpoint will return any projects or blogs whose parent is the group.

As I mentioned, Blogs are also considered places or "containers" in some respects in Jive, so they will show up in the places API responses, but it's fairly easy to ignore them. They have no children.

Please visit [Jive Community](https://community.jivesoftware.com/thread/296038) for details...